# How to derive the Electric field from the magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, dielectric, plane-wave

Given a linearly polarized, monochromatic plane wave with $H = H_0y^{cos(kz − ωt)}$ traveling in the $+\hat{z}$ direction that is incident on a dielectric sphere with permittivity $e$ and radius $a$, I am trying to derive $E$ from $H$ and then write an expression for the time-dependent dipole moment. I am just looking for suggestions on how to start!

Answer (score 1):

Writing [Maxwell equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Vacuum_equations,_electromagnetic_waves_and_speed_of_light) is a good starting point. E.g., $$\nabla\times \mathbf{H}=\mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$$ can be solved to find $\mathbf{E}$ up to a time-independent constant, which can then be further constrained by imposing equation $$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}=0$$ (if there are no external charges specified in the problem.)

Answer (score 0):

This requires a Legendre polynomial expansion.
It is a difficult problem. Study the section in an electromagnetism textbook on Legendre polynomials.  Then see how the textbook solves the problem of a dielectric sphere in a constant electric field. This will have to be extended to include the magnetic field, which will become quite complicated.